# Saving a video in FileManager doesn't work when the app reopens

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation

I am recording a video in my app and I want to save that video and play it any time I want. Everything works fine but when I reopen the app, the file is no longer available (there's no data in the file URL).

This is how I do it:

I record a video and I wait until the delegate `fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?)` hits. In this function I grab the data from the outputURL and I save it first in the user's gallery and then in the FileManager local directory:

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        if error == nil {
            try? PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChangesAndWait {
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputFileURL)
            }
            SVProgressHUD.show()

            do {
                if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: outputFileURL) {
                    let localDirectoryURL = self.saveToLocalDirectory(nameWithExtension: "\(randomString(length: 10)).mp4", data: data)
                    viewModel.outputVideoURL = localDirectoryURL ?? outputFileURL
                    viewModel.createAndSaveLocalVideo(url: localDirectoryURL ?? outputFileURL)
                } else {
                    SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "Something wrong happened")
                }
                
            }
}
```

```
func saveToLocalDirectory(nameWithExtension: String, data: Data) -> URL? {
        guard let documentDirectoryPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let path = documentDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent(nameWithExtension)
        do {
            try data.write(to: path)
            return path
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
```

I save the file URL in UserDefaults and I play try to play it. If I haven't closed the app yet, everything works as expected. But when I close the app and relaunch it I get:
`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “33eLKbc8kA.mp4” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."`

There's no errors thrown at any point and as I mentioned, it works perfect when I try to reproduce it through that URL in the same app session.

Right now I'm recording 10-15 seconds video but I will be recording up to 60 to 75 minutes. It's not in 4K and it weights around 500mb when its a 60 min video.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design the path to documents directory will change every time you reopen your application. So instead of saving a full URL you should only save the last part of your URL (file name most likely).

So simply save your `nameWithExtension` and then recreate full path by having something like

```
func urlForVideo(nameWithExtension: String) -> URL? {
    return FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent(nameWithExtension)
}
```

and use this code both when loading and saving your file.